# Is it possible to add another passenger when reserving for my round trip ticket, so we can get adjacent seats?

Tags: tickets, seating, minors

I am planning to go back home. The thing is, I am going home alone, but will be returning with my daughter.

Is it possible to get a ticket with one departing, and two return? So we can get seats next to one another since she is a minor.

Comment: You can buy two separate tickets and then have the reservations linked.

Comment: yes seats next to one another since she is a minor.

Comment: You don't say where you're flying or what airline(s), but many have online options for picking your seating. Book your flights 'home', then go online and open 2 browsers - one for your reservation, one for hers - and pick 2 seats next to each other at the same time. That should ensure that they're both available at the same time. If you log in to your flight, pick a seat, then log out and log into hers, your seat that _had_ empty space next to it may not anymore.

Comment: @FreeMan, no i havent decided what airline im going to purchase my/our tickets because i do not know what to do as of this moment. i am considering the amount of money that i will be spending.

Comment: @FreeMan, im flying from Canada to Manila Philippines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Is it possible to get a ticket with one departing, and two return?"

For the scenario you describe, **NO**.

However, you can make two separate bookings than have the airline (you will have to call unless you do it on the phone initially) **link the reservations**.

If one of you has status benefits, they will confer to the other for the matching segments.  The Agents will also see, more easily at least, you are travelling together.

Comment: If the reservation is linked, but still on two separate tickets, and it needs to be changed, would a passenger pay only one change fee (as if it was one ticket), or two fees (for changing two tickets)? Could the tickets be changed differently?

Comment: Most likely two tix, two fees.  But each airline can make their own policies.

Answer (score 16):

As far as I know, it is not possible; you'd be getting two tickets. All the passengers on a itinerary are supposed to fly exactly the same itinerary. So you can do it one of the following ways:

- Buy one one-way ticket for yourself, and another one-way ticket for both of you. This is what airlines want you to do - and they would love you for that - and this is what would cost you the most (unless you fly low cost).
- Buy a roundtrip for yourself and one way for your daughter (or a round trip with throwaway return for her). This is less expensive than above, but will put you on separate tickets. Usually not a big deal unless your flight is overbooked (there you might end up in a situation when one of you is onboard, while another one is not). Also if your daughter is a minor, some airlines would stuff you right away for an "unaccompanied minor fee" during booking (JetBlue does that, for example).
- Buy a roundtrip yourself, and either one way for both of you, or a roundtrip for both of you originating from your destination; throw away the returns. This is probably the cheapest way (unless you fly low cost), but it is against airline's "conditions of carriage". The penalties in reality, however, are non-existent.

Note, as stated in comments, that seat arrangement has nothing to do with having both people on the same reservation - it is possible to have two tickets and sit together, and it is possible to sit in different parts of a plane on the same reservation. The only real benefit I see from having both people on the same reservation that if your flight is canceled, you both would be rebooked into the same flight (with different tickets you might be rebooked to different flights), but this could be handled through the agent.

Comment: So does JetBlue insist on looking after the minor for you even when you show up together?

Comment: They ask you to pay extra $100 "unaccompanied minor fee" as part of booking when you book the minor ticket. Not sure if they'd insist on looking up after the minor if you show up together, but I really doubt they'd refund $100 because of that.

Comment: wow... i think all of the options youve presented are quite expensive.my daughter is a minor and this will be her first time flying so i think she would be scared if she and i will be put in a different seats.

Comment: Seat arrangement has nothing to do with the number of tickets. Most airlines allow you to change seats in the time of booking (some for fee), and you can choose seats together. Even if you don't, usually a gate agent or flight attendant would be able to seat you together if you ask. This is common.

Comment: I just want to emphasize that the round trip you buy for your daughter (or both of you) in the third option is using the opposite direction from your round trip. So the trip your daughter takes is the first trip on that ticket and the skipped trip is the return trip since the airline will cancel a return trip if you don't take the first trip.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: correct, I clarified it.

Answer (score 7):

With most airlines you can reserve seats, sometimes for a fee, well in advance of a flight - so just reserve yours and you daughter's at the same time. If you can't do that or fail to do so it is *very* likely that asking a member of cabin crew will lead to passengers being moved as required to allow the two of you to sit together. Airlines do not like to seat minors next to strangers.

Comment: And, _most_ strangers are accommodating of younger children traveling with their parents and would be willing to switch seats. _Some_, of course, are not.